# Wordpress wp_nav_menu not showing current page link

Tags: wordpress

I have a header menu in my Wordpress Theme and display this menu as such

```
<?php
    wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'header-menu', 'container' => false));
?>
```

My header menu contains links of both category and pages (e.g. Contact page). This menu display fine, and works as intended when I'm logged in. However, when I'm viewing my site as a public visitor, whenever I access the Contact page, the menu just doesn't display the Contact link. I've no clue why and have searched high and low on the internet but could not find any solution. The category links display fine.

Can someone help me? I want all the links to show on my header menu regardless of where my visitor is on the site.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: provide link so we can check

Comment: I'm currently running it on Instant Wordpress, so unfortunately no live site link =(

Comment: Check the post status of the Contact page. Sounds like it's private or unpublished.

Comment: It's published and public, same issue with other themes or any other pages

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out why my site was behaving this way. Apparently I have a plugin Power Menus activated which is causing this problem. I've disabled it and now its running fine.